# in jmultiselect2side yii extension, i cant see the selected list after update data

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-extensions

I am using `jmultiselect2side yii` extension, I don't find the option will show selected list updated, the code example is:

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.jmultiselect2side.Jmultiselect2side',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute'=>'gossip_id', //selected items
                'labelsx'=>'Disponible',
                'labeldx'=>'Gossip Selected',
                'moveOptions'=>false,
                'autoSort'=>'true',
                'search' =>'Search:',
                'list'=>CHtml::listData(            // available items
                   $gossips,
                   'gossip_id',
                   'gossip_name'),
            ));
```

In action update, not able to see the updated list (seleceted items), please help me

Comment: i am using this jmultiselect2side. but i did not get your question please explain bit more